# MySQL alternative to union?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to think of an alternative method to use instead of `UNION`.

I have 20 queries like this, which i plan to connect via `UNION`, to prevent multiple mysql connections.

```
$data = $DB2->query("SELECT parent.*,link.tag_ID as tag_ID FROM items parent
            JOIN relations link on link.item_ID=parent.ID
            JOIN tags child on child.ID=link.tag_ID
            WHERE child.handle='$handle' LIMIT ".$limit.",1");
```

Instead of doing this query 20 times and connecting them via `UNION`, is there an alternate method to simplify the full query or is `UNION` the best method?  both `handle` and `$limit` are dynamic for each select query.

How do i solve?

Alternatively, instead of using LIMIT

```
$data = $DB2->query("SELECT parent.*,link.tag_ID as tag_ID FROM items parent
                JOIN relations link on link.item_ID=parent.ID
                JOIN tags child on child.ID=link.tag_ID
                WHERE child.handle='$handle' AND parent.`no`='$limit' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: I can't think of any other way if they each have different `LIMIT` values.

Comment: @Barmar check edit, is `UNION` still the most simplified method without using `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have different `LIMIT` amounts for each query, you can combine them into a single query that uses `OR`. To get 1 value for each `child.handle` and `parent.no`, you can use `GROUP BY`.

```
$data = $DB2->query("SELECT parent.*,link.tag_ID as tag_ID FROM items parent
            JOIN relations link on link.item_ID=parent.ID
            JOIN tags child on child.ID=link.tag_ID
            WHERE (child.handle='$handle1' AND parent.`no`='$limit1')
            OR (child.handle='$handle2' AND parent.`no`='$limit2')
            OR (child.handle='$handle3' AND parent.`no`='$limit3')
            OR (child.handle='$handle4' AND parent.`no`='$limit4')
            ...
            GROUP BY child.handle, parent.no");
```

However, this might not be better than doing the `UNION` query, as MySQL is not very good at optimizing queries with `OR` conditions.

Comment: Thanks, what would you recommend `UNION` or `OR`?